# error "group() got an unexpected keyword argument 'observed' " when using the demo

Tags: featuretools

I tried the demo. When I run 
[in] feature_matrix, features_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es, target_entity="customers")

I got an error message like this
 group() got an unexpected keyword argument 'observed'

looking forward to your help. Thanks.

Comment: can you make sure to update to the latest version of pandas? observed is an argument they added in a later release